# Double Tap inside UIScrollView to Another View

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiscrollview, double-click

I want to preface this question with the fact I am new to the iphone application development and many times believe I may be over my head. I am trying to find an action that will allow me to double tap anywhere within my full screen UIScrollView to return to my main menu (MainMenuViewController).

I currently have the following code running for my ScrollViewController...

```
ScrollViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{

}

@end

ScrollViewController.m

#import "ScrollViewController.h"

UIScrollView *myScrollView;
UIPageControl *myPageControl;

@implementation ScrollViewController

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(UIView *)page
{
int pageCount = [[myScrollView subviews] count];

CGRect bounds = myScrollView.bounds;
bounds.origin.x = bounds.size.width * pageCount;
bounds.origin.y = 0;
page.frame = bounds;
[myScrollView addSubview:page];
}

...etc
```

Any advice or sample code to implement a double tap within the ScrollView Controller to allow me to return to my MainMenuViewController would be greatly appreciated. Also please include any Interface Builder changes to the view (if necessary). I have been pouring over the forums for days and have not been able to successfully implement this action. Thanks...R.J.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a subclass of a UIScrollView:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyScrollView : UIScrollView {
}

@end
```

Implement it:

```
#import "MyScrollView.h"

@implementation MyScrollView

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {

    if (!self.dragging) {
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
    }       
    [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Then, use this subclass instead of a normal UIScrollView in your main View Controller. This will call the touchesEnded:withEvent: method (alternatively, you can call any method you want). Then, track for double taps (if you need info on how to do that, let me know).